# What are the proper notations for these probability objects

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, notation, conditional-probability

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma, P)$ be a probability space where $\Omega$ is a (possibly infinite) state space and $\Sigma$ is the $\sigma$ algebra. Let $S$ be a finite set, and $f: \Omega\to \Delta(S)$ be a $\Sigma$-measurable function, where $\Delta(S)$ denotes all probability distributions over $S$.

Then $P$ and $f$ define a probability measure $Q\in \Delta(S\times \Omega)$ by
$$dQ(s,\omega)=f(s|\omega)dP(\omega)\tag{*}$$

Conversely, for any $Q$, I think we can define the corresponding $f$ and $P$.

My question is the following: is the above notation $(*)$ legitimate? What would be the standard notation for $dQ(a,\omega)$ in measure theory?

For another question, suppose $\Omega=\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$, for integration purpose, I need to define the conditional probabilty measure for $\omega_1$ given any $\omega_2$ by  something like

$$dP(\omega_1|\omega_2)=P(\tilde{\omega}_1=\omega_1|\tilde{\omega}_2=\omega_2) \tag{**}$$

What would be the standard notation for $dP(\omega_1|\omega_2)$?

Thanks.

Comment: Notation $\Delta(S)$?  When $Q$ has two variables, I would not put the $d$ outside (since it does not tell us which variable), instead perhaps $$Q(s,d\omega)=f(s|\omega)P(d\omega)$$

Comment: Thanks! Here $\Delta(S)$ denote the probability distribution over $S$. I will add it to the question.  So would it be proper to write  $P(d\omega_1|\omega_2)$, where $P(d\omega_1|\omega_2)$ appears at the end of an integral?

Comment: Do not expect your reader to understand these notations.  The first time you write it, provide a fuller definition ... $$\int_\Omega\phi(\omega)\;Q(s,d\omega) = \cdots\quad\text{or} \quad Q(s,E) = \cdots$$

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I understand it, you want to define a probability measure on $S\times \Omega$ from a probability measure on $\Omega$ and a conditional distribution on $S$ given the information on $\Omega$, is that correct?